# In Kotlin, is there a way to add one more value into enum by a function call?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, enums

I have an enum, for example

```
enum class User(val userInfo: UserInfo){
    USER_A( NewUser(A) ),
    USER_B( NewUser(B) ),
    USER_C( NewUser(C) ),
}
```

Now I want to add one user to the `User` enum, can I do something like this?

`User.add( "USER_D", NewUser(D) )`

From my point of view, since enum is constant and created at compile time, I think it's impossible. But dose anyone know a workaround that can realize something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the number of users is dynamic then you should not be using an enum for this in the first place.

Comment: 100% with what Slaw has said, could I ask why you want to achieve this ?

Comment: Thanks! It's just an example. In the real project the enum is not for user @Slaw

Comment: What the enum represents in your real project is irrelevant in this context. If the number of instances of _any type_ is dynamic then you should not be using an enum.

Answer (score 1):

Enum properties are converted to plain static final instances. I think the closest thing is to use a simple map:

```kotlin
class User(val info: UserInfo)
val users = mutableMapOf("USER_A" to User(A))
```

Unfortunately, there are no accessors checked in compiletime like `users.USER_A`, but it is not completely possible since the map is mutated in runtime.

Comment: Hi @miller-dong if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot modify types at runtime. You could emit new types, but modifying existing ones is not possible. Having an enum value is, in my opinion, preferable over dictionaries or list based solution as one uses less memory and no thread side effects.